# R markdown won't knit to html on Mac

Tags: html, r, markdown, ascii, knitr

I am trying to knit an Rmarkdown to html on both mac and windows. In this file there is a lot of text data that is being processed into text columns using the R package gt.  In windows, the code runs fine, without any issue.

When I try to run the same code on a mac, I get this error:

```
Error in gsub("&#39;", "'", html_tbl) : input string 1 is invalid
```

I know what the issue is: there is an apostrophe in a text string which comes off looking like a question mark in a black diamond in the raw data:

```
"...think a lot of us didn�t quite understand wh..."
```

What I don't understand is, why does the code fail on an ios and not on a windows; what can I do to fix this and prevent this issue going forward, and if possible how can I fix this issue so that the sentence passed to the html output maintains its' original meaning and composition.

Edit: This is how the file is read:

```
df_import <- read_csv("file_path")
```

Comment: Are your packages up-to-date on your Mac? Specifically, `rmarkdown`, `rmarkdown`, and `knitr`? And maybe even RStudio?

Comment: Oops, meant `markdown` and `rmarkdown`

Comment: The issue might be related to the character encoding of the text file and different default encoding settings on windows and macOS. If you use a `readr` function to read the document, check if `default_locale()` shows the same encoding on both systems. To be able to help you better, please add an R code snippet to your question that shows how you read the data, and the part of the code that produces the error.

Comment: I've checked and all the packages are up to date. I've added the read function of the code as well to the question.

Comment: And the default_locale() shows the same encoding across both systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like encoding issue. So you can try to read the csv with encoding. What you should do is:

- First detect encoding with the uchardet library `uchardet::detect_file_enc("csv_file.csv")`
- Second read the file with encoding, for instance using one of these:

`readr::read_csv2("csv_file.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "WINDOWS-1252"))`

`readr::read_csv2("csv_file.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "latin1"))`

`readr::read_csv2("csv_file.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))`

Comment: You're right, it was an encoding issue. I used the latin1 encoding and that was able to get me past this issue. The package you linked, uchardet is no longer on CRAN though. However, the readr package has a function called guess_encoding that does the same thing.